# How do I install new actions in a self hosted github actions runner?

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

Our organization uses GitHub enterprise. We’ve deployed our own self hosted runner in a basic Amazon instance. The instance is missing various actions that we would like to use in our workflows.  I can’t seem to find any documentation or information on how to install actions in our self-hosted runner.

Comment: Aren't actions always fetched from remote, even for self-hosted runners?

Answer (score 0):

### GitHub Connect

[If your GitHub Enterprise instance is configured with GitHub Connect it can fetch these actions automatically from public GitHub repositories.](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.10/admin/github-actions/managing-access-to-actions-from-githubcom/enabling-automatic-access-to-githubcom-actions-using-github-connect)

### Actions sync

Alternatively, you can [use the `actions-sync` tool that now ships with GitHub Actions to automatically pull in the latest version](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.10/admin/github-actions/managing-access-to-actions-from-githubcom/manually-syncing-actions-from-githubcom).

### Forking

If your GitHub Enterprise Server isn't connected to GitHub Enterprise Cloud, then you can "fork" the actions to your own Enterpise instance. You can `git clone --mirror` the action from the internet and then `git push --mirror` the contents into an empty repo in your own enterprise instance.

If you forked the action and it was originally called `jessehouwig/actions-semver-checker` you'd have to replace `jessehouwing` with the name or your organization.

Comment: This has to be done on the enterprise level or can the action just be installed within the runner itself?

Comment: Actions need to be installed in the enterprise/organization. The runner will download them from the enterprise.